# Getting undefined value from this.props.match.params on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, axios, react-props

I am new developer **ReactJS**, I develop a table with **ReactJS** on the FrontEnd, **NodeJS** on BackEnd and **MySQL** about the database.

I want when I click on the view button on Action column, it will be redirected to another page, which display a list containing the result of the Select query, as below :

[image]

My viewClient.js :

```
class ViewClient extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clients:[]

        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            activeTab: '1',
        };
    }

    toggle(tab) {
        if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
            this.setState({
                activeTab: tab,
            });
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {


         axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/' +this.props.match.params.Code)

            .then(response => {
                if (response && response.data) {
                    this.setState({ clients: response.data });
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    } 

    render() {
        let { clients } = this.state;
        // let { clients } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <Row>

           <Col xs="12" md="6" className="mb-4">
            <Nav tabs>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                  className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '1' })}
                  onClick={() => { this.toggle('1'); }}
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-info"></i> <span className={this.state.activeTab === '1' ? '' : 'd-none'}> Détails</span>
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                  className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '2' })}
                  onClick={() => { this.toggle('2'); }}
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-credit-card"></i> <span
                  className={this.state.activeTab === '2' ? '' : 'd-none'}> Factures</span>
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink
                  className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '3' })}
                  onClick={() => { this.toggle('3'); }}
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-truck"></i> <span className={this.state.activeTab === '3' ? '' : 'd-none'}> Bons de livraison</span>
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
            <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab} style={{ height:"420px"}}>
              <TabPane tabId="1">
               <ul>
               {
                       clients &&  clients.map(client => (
                            <li key={client.Code}>
                         <h1> Code client :    {client.Code} </h1>
                             {client.Prenom}
                              {client.Nom}
                              {client.FAX}
                             {client.Telephone}
                               {client.Email}
                                {client.Adresse1}
                                 {client.Adresse2}
               </li>
               ))}
               </ul>
              </TabPane>
              <TabPane tabId="2">

              </TabPane>
              <TabPane tabId="3">

              </TabPane>
            </TabContent>
          </Col>

        </Row>
      </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ViewClient;
```

My router :

```
exports.viewclient = function(req, res) {
  var Code = req.params.Code;
    console.log(req.params);

    connection.query('SELECT Code, Prenom, Nom, FAX, Telephone, Email, Adresse1, Adresse2  FROM clients  WHERE Code = ?',[req.params.Code],  function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
console.log(results);
    });

}
```

My server :

```
var express    = require("express");
var login = require('./routes/loginroutes');
var clients = require('./routes/clientroutes');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000/');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', ['PATCH', 'POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT']);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', ['Content-Type']);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', ['Content-Type']);
    /* res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");*/
    next();
});
app.use(cors());


var router = express.Router();

// test route
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'welcome to our upload module apis' });
});

//route to handle user registration
router.post('/register', login.register);
router.post('/login', login.login);
router.post('/ajouterclient', clients.ajouterclient);
router.get('/listeclients', clients.listeclients);
router.get('/viewclient/:Code', clients.viewclient);
router.get('/editclient', clients.editclient);
//route to handle file printing and listing

app.use('/app', router);
app.listen(4000);
```

When I run the backend, it works well with *Postman* with url  `http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/1111` and it returns `[{"Code":1111,"Prenom":"test","Nom":"test","FAX":"58985688888","Telephone":"58985699888","Email":"test@gmail.com","Adresse1":"","Adresse2":""}]`, but when I run it with ReactJS, it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/app/viewclient/` but nothing is displayed and  `console.log(this.props.match.params.Code)` returns `undefined`

How to fix that please ?

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) instead so it will be easier to help you?

Comment: Are you defining `Code` in express router and then trying to access it from react router?

Comment: @Tholle , you can see the code here : https://codesandbox.io/embed/1zx3lo6zqj?view=editor

Comment: @wdm I used Code on my router here : `var Code = req.params.Code;
    console.log(req.params);
  connection.query('SELECT Code, Prenom, Nom, FAX, Telephone, Email, Adresse1, Adresse2  FROM clients  WHERE Code = ?',[req.params.Code], `

Comment: @wdm can you see the code here https://codesandbox.io/embed/1zx3lo6zqj?view=editor ? I have a class List, which redirects the button to `/viewclient/:Code` In fact, I want when I click on the button view, it will be redirected to another page , which display all the details of this row.

Comment: @CodeLover are you using React Router on the front end? If so can you post the code where you define the relevant route with the `:Code` param?

Comment: @CodeLover your `handleView` method pushes to `this.props.history.push("/clients/viewclient/")` there's no specific `Code` defined

Comment: @wdm  How to define the relevant route with  `:Code` param ?

Comment: @wdm  I edit the method on `handleView` to `this.props.history.push('/clients/viewclient/'+this.props.match.params.Code);` but when I run  it, It redirects to `http://localhost:3000/app/viewclient/undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176134/discussion-between-codelover-and-wdm).